# parallelStream for time consuming methods

Tags: java, java-stream

I have something like this:

```
// sequential version
for(var t: tasks){ 
    // run() is a time consuming method (approx. 20-30 seconds)
    t.run();
}
```

I have approx. 1000 (independent) tasks and the above needs approx. 1000 x 25 seconds. The `run()`-method is **only** CPU intensive (there are **no** I/O Operations involved).

I switched to parallelStream:

```
// parallel version
tasks.parallelStream().forEach(Task:run);
```

and measured that with `parallelStream` each `task.run()` needs approx. 15-20 seconds. So it's definitely a little faster than using the sequential version.

Can I use `parallelStream` (with its fork-join) for such long running operations (each `task.run()` needs approx. 15-20 seconds) or would it be better to use `executorServices` with custom thread pools (for example, because of system stability, performance, etc.)?

What I want to know if there is any harm when using `parallelStream` (fork-join) for such long running tasks. I have thought that fork-join should only be used for very short running tasks (max. 1-2 seconds), but I am not sure if so and why.

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I can't think of what concern there would be with 20 second tasks here. Are there dependencies between tasks or are they all independent?

Comment: @NathanHughes 1000 (*independent*) tasks..

Comment: I/O bound? CPU intensive?

Comment: Only CPU intensive. Each independent task does a time consuming calculation (within `run()`) and nothing else.

Comment: The purpose of a parallel stream is to get a better *overall time*. Posting what “each task” is needing, is confusing. Does “approx. 15-20 seconds” really mean that each task became surprisingly faster or did you just unneededly divide the overall time by 1000? Getting from 25,000 s to 15,000 s would be good if you have a dualcore CPU only, otherwise, it would be a bad result for 1,000 independent tasks. If you don’t have a reason nor cite for your “short running only” idea, allows us to dismiss that idea without the need for a reason nor cite either.

Answer (score 3):

[`Collection#parallelStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html#parallelStream()) is simpler - you need less code, but you have no control over when, or even if, parallelism is used.

[`ExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) gives you a lot of control over parallel processing, but exposes more of the workings, so you need more code and more knowledge (but not a *lot* of either).

Try parallel stream first. If that seems good enough and you’re not processing many other requests, stop there.

If parallelism seems not be to sufficient, or if you are processing other requests, use executor service, because all streams share a single thread pool, so if they are kept busy, other stream based code will freeze.

Comment: Thanks. I know how to use executor service with custom threads. That's not the problem. What I wanted to know if there is any harm when using parallelStream (fork-join) for such long running tasks. I have thought that fork-join should only be used for very short running tasks (max. 1-2 seconds), but I am not sure if so and why.

Comment: @nimo23 The “harm” with parallel streams is the stream decides when or if it executes in parallel, not you.

Comment: I know this. Assume, that the system has decided to execute in parallel. The question is: Is it good for such long running tasks to use parallelStream (with its common fork-join)

Comment: @nimo23 Ah. Liveliness of your app may be affected by parallel streams. Use ExecutorService for heavy lifting if you concurrently serve different short lived purposes.

Comment: If possible, please explain the statement "Liveliness of your app may be affected by parallel streams." a little more and why that can happen in my case (for long running tasks).

Comment: @nimo23 Liveliness of your app.. : It means your program may fail to make progress or may not respond in a timely manner. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/liveness.html)

Comment: @nimo23 liveliness means other requests may hang (freeze) due to thread pool starvation. All streams share a single thread pool - if all of those threads are busy, other code that uses steams will halt.

Comment: @Bohemian since for every stream operation, at least the caller thread will work on it, there is no halt. But having significantly more CPU bound threads than cores will slow down any progress, whether you use the Stream API or not.